# Connect exception in gatling- What does this mean?

Tags: performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

I ran the below config in gatling from my local machine to verify 20K requests per second ..

```
 scn
  .inject(
    atOnceUsers(20000)
  )
```

It gave these below error in reports...What des this mean in gatling?

> j.n.ConnectException: Can't assign requested address:
>   /xx.xx.xx:xxxx    3648    83.881 %
>
> j.n.ConnectException: connection timed out: /xx.xx.xx:xxxx    416 9.565 %
>   status.find.is(200), but actually found 500   201 4.622 %
>
> j.u.c.TimeoutException: Request timeout to not-connected after
>   60000ms   84  1.931 %

Are these timeouts happening due to server not processing the requests or requests not going from my local machine

Answer (score 0):

Most probably yes, that's the reason.
Seems your simulation was compiled successfully and started.
If you look to the error messages you will see percentages after each line (83.881%, 9.565%, 1.931 %). This means that actually the requests were generated and were sent and some of them failed. Percentages are counted based on total number of fails.
If some of the requests are OK and you get these errors, then Gatling did its job. It stress tested your application.
Try to simulate with lower number of users,for example:

```
scn
 inject(
  rampUsers(20) over (10 seconds)
)
```

If it works then definitely your application is not capable to handle 20000 requests at once.

For more info on how to setup a simulation see [here](https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/general/simulation_setup/).